# Invalid Host IP Error when sending an SMS

Tags: ideamart

I have been trying to send an SMS using the PHP ideamart wrapper and I am getting the following error.

```
Invalid Host IP Error
```

This is the request I made to `https://api.dialog.lk/sms/send`

`{
  "message": "Hello",
  "destinationAddresses": ["tel:94777123456"],
  "password": "password",
  "applicationId": "APP_999999"
}`

Can anyone help me to figure out the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple of tries I figured out the cause of the issue, It is a problem with my web hosting service. Since Ideamart API only allow requests from `whitelisted/allowed IP address`.

I have requested the outgoing IP from the hosting provider and added it to the `provisioning`. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ideamart API only allows whitelisted IP for a apps when you provisioned. So first get your host's IP address and use it as a whitelisted IP.

Since app is already provisioned you need to send support request to ideamart to alter it.